# Default to "no limit" for maximum number of options in field type select

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

The number of cities and sectors "small cities" in Moldova is around thousand,so we have already exceeded the arbitrary 100 limit without half-trying.

The limit causes problems when we translate the options.

We get message translations were saved successfully, however going back to translation noting is saved.

Looking into server logs we found out there is a problem with max_input_vars in php.ini

> 2016/02/02 11:37:26 [error] 1310#0: *199007 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To
>   increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on
>   line 0"

We updated the php.ini file and set the max_input_vars = 5000. After that the Error above disappeared, however we are still unable to save the translations and there is no error in the server console logs.

Is there anything we can do about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase  `post_max_size` value or disable the limit by setting it to `0`